# Assigning value to graph nodes in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I am generating a 2D graph with adjacency matrix. I would like to assign the values of the nodes (1-9) with matrix `P1`. Node `1` is assigned `1.09730075`, 2 is assigned `0.30837859`, 3 is assigned `1.59680266`, 4 is assigned `1.26296281` and so on...

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3,3)
new_nodes = {e: n for n, e in enumerate(G.nodes, start=1)}
new_edges = [(new_nodes[e1], new_nodes[e2]) for e1, e2 in G.edges]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(new_edges)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

A1 = nx.adjacency_matrix(G) 
A=A1.toarray()
print([A]) #for obtaining a random adjacency matrix


P1=np.array([[1.09730075, 0.30837859, 1.59680266],
       [1.26296281, 0.57485091, 1.17281021],
       [1.37259558, 1.33184676, 0.64522432]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `networkx`, but from what I understood, this might be what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

P1 = np.array([[1.09730075, 0.30837859, 1.59680266],
               [1.26296281, 0.57485091, 1.17281021],
               [1.37259558, 1.33184676, 0.64522432]])

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3, 3)

new_nodes = {e: P1[n // 3, n % 3] for n, e in enumerate(G.nodes)}
new_edges = [(new_nodes[e1], new_nodes[e2]) for e1, e2 in G.edges]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(new_edges)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True
```

When creating `new_nodes`, it uses the value of `n` to identify which position of np array to index, and uses the weight specified at that position.

Comment: I think this assigns labels to the nodes. I would like to have the nodes to take values according to the matrix mentioned along with the usual labels as shown above.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's possible, at least from what I could find. You could try something like `new_nodes = {e: str((n, P1[n // 3, n % 3])) for n, e in enumerate(G.nodes)}`.